# MongoEngine QuerySet insert call default function twice

Tags: python, model, insert, mongoengine

I have to insert multiple record and there is method [`insert`](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.insert) for the `QuerySet` in `mongoengine` which allow to create a multiple record using single method call.

My model has `default` method, which should be call, if there is no attribute assigned for the column. But, in case of `insert` we have to provide the `Document` object, and when we create a `Document` object, at that time, it call the default value, and second time it call the default value when we do `insert`. I have code like below.

```
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine import StringField


def get_name():
    print("*"*80)
    print('getname')
    print("*"*80)
    return 'first_name'


class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50, default=get_name)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from mongoengine import connect
    connect('test', host="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test")
    m = User(email='test@test.com')

    User.objects.insert(m)
```

And When I run it, it gives output like.

```
python /tmp/test.py
********************************************************************************
getname
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
getname
********************************************************************************
```

means `get_name` called when we do `m = User(email='test@test.com')` and second time it called when `User.objects.insert(m)`.

My real default function is incrementing the number, and with this, it increment 2 times.

I know, we can use `Document.save` to save the document, but in case of `multiple` entry, I have to call `save` multiple time.

Is there anyway, to make sure `default` function call only once ?